# Where is there an understandable documentation for the wdm.h c header

Tags: c++, c, kernel, driver, windows-kernel

I was wondering if there was a possible way to embed regular c/c++ inside a windows kernel mode driver. I've been doing some research and it seems pretty impossible, considering that the print function already looks like
`KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "KmdfHelloWorld: KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd\n"));`.
Also, the docs look really really confusing and I can't understand them, eg the syntax for making a file is ....                        
 **Note stack overflow though I was spamming so I have to give a link instead**
https://pastebin.com/0tAz4YSE
Basically I'm just wondering where a comprehensive way to learn the syntax for drivers is.

Comment: What language do you think most drivers are written in? Hint, it's in your list.

Comment: @RetiredNinja C i believe

Comment: So, what is your question? What does "embed regular c/c++" mean if a driver is already written in C or C++?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Ok sorry, it's a bit confusing I basically just need a documentation of the kernel mode C driver syntax where it isn't written in a way that makes it really hard to understand

Comment: @RetiredNinja Also if i put regular c in a driver will it still run in kernel mode?

Comment: I believe the question (poorly worded as it is) is about regular standard library functionality. And the answer is that the kernel provides analogues of what it can but it really is a very different environment.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir ok thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So You want a Pretty Good Documentation for learning about Drivers? Here are few I Suggest
Microsoft KMDF : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver

So If you are a starter learn with User mode Drivers as they are easier to use
Microsoft UMDF : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/overview-of-the-umdf

Driver Concepts :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/what-is-a-driver-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/concepts-and-knowledge-for-all-driver-developers

These are Android Drivers :
https://source.android.com/devices/

Linux Too Has a Pretty Good Documentation :
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/index.html